# Open csv file using python(IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: "['C:\\\\bigdata)

Tags: python, csv

when i want to open a csv file and inport to my sqlite,

this is my code:

```
import os
import csv
import sqlite3
import string

connection = sqlite3.connect('nba.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
officialbatch_file = []

for dirPath, dirNames, PlayoffsfileNames in os.walk('C:\\bigdata_nba\\rawdata\\teamgamelogbatch'):
    for f in PlayoffsfileNames:
        officialbatch_file.append(os.path.join(dirPath, f))
        csvfile = open(str(officialbatch_file),'r')
        creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"')

        new_f = f[:15]
        cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+str(new_f))
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE '+str(new_f)+'(Team_ID text, Game_ID text, GAME_DATE , YEAR date,TEAM text, MATCHUP text,RIVAL_TEAM text, WL text, MIN integer, FGM integer, FGA integer, FG_PCT integer, FG3M integer, FG3A integer, FG3_PCT integer, FTM integer, FTA integer, FT_PCT integer, OREB integer, DREB integer, REB integer, AST integer, STL integer, BLK integer, TOV integer, PF integer, PTS integer, VIDEO_AVAILABLE integer)')

        connection.commit()
```

but the error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\nbadata_script\AlliInOneTeamGameLogRegularSeason.py", line 14, in <module>
    csvfile = open(str(officialbatch_file),'r')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: "['C:\\\\bigdata_nba\\\\rawdata\\\\teamgamelogbatch\\\\1610612737\\\\Playoffs\\\\TeamGameLog1987-88Playoffs.csv']"
```

I've try a lot by now so a little help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: you should use `with open(filename, mode) as some_file: ` This ensures the file will always be closed when the block is left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open the string version of a **list**:

```
officialbatch_file.append(os.path.join(dirPath, f))
csvfile = open(str(officialbatch_file),'r')
```

You want *just* the full path here, not the list of filenames:

```
fullname = os.path.join(dirPath, f)
officialbatch_file.append(fullname)
csvfile = open(fullname, 'rb')
```

I'm assuming here you *also* wanted to maintain the list of filenames in the `officialbatch_file` list. If not, you can remove all references to `officialbatch_file`.

If this is Python 2, you should open CSV files in binary mode (e.g. `'rb'`), the `csv` module handles line endings explicitly. In Python 3, use `open(fullname, 'rb', newline='')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use forward slashes "/" in path example -->('C:/bigdata_nba/rawdata/teamgamelogbatch'):